# Getting historical price for specific dates using R

Tags: r, quantmod, stock

I am trying to get the past 4 fiscal years' stock price, which are the close price for each specific date from yahoo using R.

The following is:

```
getFin("AAPL")
viewFin(AAPL.f, "IS", "A")
x <- viewFin(AAPL.f, "IS", "A")
y <- colnames(x)
getSymbols("AAPL")
AAPL[y]
```

But I find that I can not get the price while I was using AAPL[y], it gave me nothing.

Can someone give me a hand? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

`AAPL[y]` returned an empty xts object because AAPL didn't trade on those dates.  You can get the previous close by merging `AAPL` with an empty xts object containing the `y` Dates and using `na.locf`.

Note that if `fill` is a function, the function will be applied to the result of the merge before `merge` returns.  It's a handy feature.

```
merge(AAPL, xts(,sort(as.Date(y))), fill=na.locf)[y,]
```